# Calling Google query returns: Error:"invalid_grant", Description:"", Uri:"" on 1 machine, but not the other

Tags: google-oauth

I'm making the same  API calls as the below threads:

- [TokenResponseException - Error:"invalid_grant", Description:"", Uri:""](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27737230/tokenresponseexception-errorinvalid-grant-description-uri)
- [Google Analytics API 3 - Error:"invalid_grant", Description:"", Uri:""](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25386558/google-analytics-api-3-errorinvalid-grant-description-uri)

I know the code, service account e-mail and certificate works, because it works on one machine.

However, when I copy the code and certificate file to another machine, it fails with the TokenResponseExpection -invalid_grant.

I've checked time is in sync on both machines, and I've got the right certificate/code what else can I check to debug this?

Comment: I have the same setup working on 2 machines, but failing on 1. Any ideas on how to debug would be most appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

Is the windows time of your machine right? Google API uses a timestamp for the authorisation token that can cause this error

Answer (score 0):

I think nobody knows why this is happening, I wasnt able to find any answer.
I did my own investigation right here: [TokenResponseException - Error:"invalid_grant", Description:"", Uri:""](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27737230/tokenresponseexception-errorinvalid-grant-description-uri?lq=1)
and here: [How to acquire a new Access token using Refresh token in Google OAuth 2.0 in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35724361/how-to-acquire-a-new-access-token-using-refresh-token-in-google-oauth-2-0-in-ne)

And it is still unknown why this is happening.
I though it has something to do with access token expiration, but I am not sure, I wasn't able to figure out, AFAIU credentials token must aquire a new access token upon its expiration automatically when accessing Google API with a credentials token that contains expired access token and refresh token assigned (that was received the very first time and saved). And of course there is a limit of how many access tokens you can request - 25, or you ganna get "Invalid Grant: The refresh token limit has been exceeded (default is 25)."

The Token is an object that contains 2 other objects: AccessToken and RefreshToken. If RefreshToken is set to a value received upon authentication, then, if AccessToken expires after 1 hour, when you make a call to Google API, it should use the RefreshToken to acquire a new AccessToken. How exactly it does that - no idea, it should be internal hidden implementation of Google API.

Or I could be mistaken :)